# Unexpected Termination when loading data from excel using ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, database-administration, ssis-2016

I have SSIS package which simply loads data from excel using microsoft.ace.oledb. 12.0 driver to a sql server table.

The excel file size is 4.5mb

It is running fine locally.

When I delploy and run using Sql Server Agent in development enviroment, the job is failing with status 'Unexpected Termination'(after post validation and on information).  I am not able to troubleshoot as there is no error message.

Please note development enviroment is exact image copy of my local.
This is only occurring for large excel files.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66985851/ssis-error-when-run-via-sql-job-while-connecting-to-ms-access-database-unexpect/67232944#67232944

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255 is installed on the server the SSIS package is running on so microsoft.ace.oledb. 12.0 is available. Be sure you choose the right version 64 vs 32 bit depending on how you run the package. Its probably x64 but unless you've explicitly set it to be x32.